# How do I set the startDate in an Angular-Bootstrap ngb-datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular6

I want to use a ngb-datepicker in my application.  [According to this documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api), this compnent has a startDate input that controls the initial date of the calendar.  I can't figure out how to set this date.  Since there are no examples using this input, I have to guess.  I've tried each of these lines, but they don't work.

1. `<ngb-datepicker startDate="2018-11-01"></ngb-datepicker>`
2. `<ngb-datepicker startDate="{ year: 2018; month: 11; }"></ngb-datepicker>`
3. `<ngb-datepicker startDate.year="2018" startDate.month="11"></ngb-datepicker>`

How do I do this?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do show it in the documentation. It's in the Overview section, the "Move Around" subparagraph. And it's like this:

```
<ngb-datepicker [startDate]="{year: 2018, month: 11}"
```